# SmartConfig Specific ESP32 using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, iot, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am developing an IoT device with Android App. For the hardware, I am using ESP32. For the Android App part, I am using Flutter for the development. I managed to write the SmartConfig code using the esp_smartconfig package. This is working really fine. But the problem is it is configuring all the ESP32 in smart config mode. I want to configure only one specific device selected from the list.

I am attaching both the flutter code and ESP32-arduino code.

Flutter Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:esp_smartconfig/esp_smartconfig.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ESP SmartConfig Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // final info = NetworkInfo();
  final provisioner = Provisioner.espTouch();

  String msg = 'Press Button to Upload';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    PermissionWithService locationPermission = Permission.locationWhenInUse;

    var permissionStatus = await locationPermission.status;
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionStatus = await locationPermission.request();

      if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
        permissionStatus = await locationPermission.request();
      }
    }

    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      bool isLocationServiceOn =
          await locationPermission.serviceStatus.isEnabled;
      if (isLocationServiceOn) {
        final info = NetworkInfo();
        String ssid = await info.getWifiName() as String;
        String bssid = await info.getWifiBSSID() as String;
        // final splitted = ssid.split('"');
        // print(splitted[1]);
        // print(bssid);
        setState(() {
          msg = "Sending WiFi Details";
        });
        await provisioner.start(ProvisioningRequest.fromStrings(
            ssid: ssid.split('"')[1], bssid: bssid, password: '123454321'));
      } else {
        print('Location Service is not enabled');
      }
    }

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    provisioner.stop();
    setState(() {
      msg = "Press Button";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              msg,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

ESP32-Arduino Code:

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"
#define LENGTH(x) (strlen(x) + 1)   // length of char string
#define EEPROM_SIZE 200             // EEPROM size
#define WiFi_rst 0                  //WiFi credential reset pin (Boot button on ESP32)
#define LED 2
String ssid;                        //string variable to store ssid
String pss;                         //string variable to store password
unsigned long rst_millis;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);             //Init serial
  pinMode(WiFi_rst, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  if (!EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE)) { //Init EEPROM
    Serial.println("failed to init EEPROM");
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    ssid = readStringFromFlash(0); // Read SSID stored at address 0
    Serial.print("SSID = ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    pss = readStringFromFlash(40); // Read Password stored at address 40
    Serial.print("psss = ");
    Serial.println(pss);
  }

  WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), pss.c_str());

  delay(3500);   // Wait for a while till ESP connects to WiFi

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) // if WiFi is not connected
  {
    //Init WiFi as Station, start SmartConfig
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
    WiFi.beginSmartConfig();

    //Wait for SmartConfig packet from mobile
    Serial.println("Waiting for SmartConfig.");
    while (!WiFi.smartConfigDone()) {
      digitalWrite(LED, !digitalRead(LED));
      delay(100);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("SmartConfig received.");

    //Wait for WiFi to connect to AP
    Serial.println("Waiting for WiFi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      digitalWrite(LED, !digitalRead(LED));
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("WiFi Connected.");

    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    // read the connected WiFi SSID and password
    ssid = WiFi.SSID();
    pss = WiFi.psk();
    Serial.print("SSID:");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("PSS:");
    Serial.println(pss);
    Serial.println("Store SSID & PSS in Flash");
    writeStringToFlash(ssid.c_str(), 0); // storing ssid at address 0
    writeStringToFlash(pss.c_str(), 40); // storing pss at address 40
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  rst_millis = millis();
  while (digitalRead(WiFi_rst) == LOW)
  {
    // Wait till boot button is pressed
  }
  // check the button press time if it is greater than 3sec clear wifi cred and restart ESP
  if (millis() - rst_millis >= 3000)
  {
    Serial.println("Reseting the WiFi credentials");
    writeStringToFlash("", 0); // Reset the SSID
    writeStringToFlash("", 40); // Reset the Password
    Serial.println("Wifi credentials erased");
    Serial.println("Restarting the ESP");
    delay(500);
    ESP.restart();            // Restart ESP
  }
}


void writeStringToFlash(const char* toStore, int startAddr) {
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < LENGTH(toStore); i++) {
    EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, toStore[i]);
  }
  EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, '\0');
  EEPROM.commit();
}


String readStringFromFlash(int startAddr) {
  char in[128]; // char array of size 128 for reading the stored data
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < 128; i++) {
    in[i] = EEPROM.read(startAddr + i);
  }
  return String(in);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late to answer but, the only solution to this problem is you need provide a provision in your esp for enabling config mode. By adding this provision, the esp which are in config mode will only be configured.

Also you will need to change your approach in the application. Slecting from list will not work.